# Split the User Input String

Tags: c#, input

I want to split the User Input String to 2 Strings.

```
string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
```

I want that when the user enters e.g. "open google.com" that it is divided into 2 strings like:

```
string userinput1 = "open";
string userinput2 = "google.com";
```

And if the user types something like "open google.com example", that the word "example" gets ignored and not stored in any string :D

I hope you can help me.

Comment: `String[] words = userInput.Split( (Char[])null );`

Comment: What happens if the user enters `open up google.com`? Can you guarantee there won't be a space in any part?

Comment: Is there any chance of the user typing more than one space, or maybe using tab instead of space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) is useful.

```
string userinput = Console.ReadLine();

char[] delim = new char[]{ ' ' };
string[] splitted = userinput.Split(delim);

string userinput1 = splitted[0];
string userinput2 = splitted[1];
```

Comment: Fun fact using `null` for the separator argumen (e.g. `String.Split( (Char[])null )` ) will split on **all** whitespace, not just single ASCII space characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputSplitted = userInput.Split(null);
string userInput1 = inputSplitted[0];
string userInput2 = inputSplitted[1];
```